# Probable winner of last coin game of a series, where winner from one game has disadvantage the next game?

Tags: probability, contest-math

> Alfred and Bonnie play a game in which they take turns tossing a fair coin. The winner is the first person to obtain a head. They play this game several times, with the stipulation that the loser of a game goes first in the next game. Suppose Alfred goes first in the first game, what is the probability that he wins the 6th game?

This problem is from 1993 AIME.

---

The first player has a $\frac{2}{3}$ (from $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots$) chance of winning a particular game, while the second player has a $\frac{1}{3}$ (from $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\ldots$) chance.

Let $F_n$ be the chance of winning the last game when going first given that there are $n$ games left, and $S_n$ be the chance of winning the last game when going second and there are $n$ games left. So $F_1=\frac{2}{3},S_1=\frac{1}{3}$.

Since Alfred goes first in the first game, his chances of winning the sixth game are $F_6$. We expect this to be slightly less than a half, given that the winner of a game goes second the next game, and there are an even number of games.

The transition matrix is given by

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} F_{n+1} \\ S_{n+1} \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1/3 & 2/3 \\ 2/3 & 1/3 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{cc} F_{n} \\ S_{n} \end{array} \right)$$

Then we can compute

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} F_6 \\ S_6 \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1/3 & 2/3 \\ 2/3 & 1/3 \end{array} \right)^5 \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2/3 \\ 1/3 \end{array} \right)$$

But is there a better way?

---

#### Update

Based on Macavity's comment and Lulu's answer, the recursion can be solved to get:

$$F_n = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n$$

since $F_1=\frac{2}{3}$.

Then $F_6=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{3})^6=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{729}=\ldots$

Comment: The recursion can be simplified to $F_{n+1}=\frac23-\frac13F_n$, using $S_n=1-F_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, my first draft falsely assumed that the winner goes first in the next game.  I have corrected this below.

Well, I'm not sure it's better, but here's a different method.

Proceed by recursion. Let $P(n)$ denote the probability that $A$ wins the $n^{th}$ game.  The answer you want is, of course, $P(6)$.  It isn't hard to compute $$P(1)=\frac 23$$

Now, take the first game.  Either $A$ wins (probability $\frac 23$) or $A$ loses (probability $\frac 13$).  If $A$ loses then he is back at the start, with $n-1$ games to go (so his probability of winning from here is $P(n-1)$).  If $A$ wins, we still have $n-1$ games to go, but now $A$ goes second, so his chances of winning from here are $1-P(n-1)$.  Thus we have the recursion:

$$P(n)=\frac 13 P(n-1)\;+\;\frac 23 (1-P(n))=\frac {2-P(n-1)}3$$

This is fairly easy to work with.  In particular, we get $P(6) \sim .49931$

Comment: @Macavity   Thank you.  I noticed that (belatedly) and have made the necessary changes.  Or at least, I have tried to.